# How do you filter and sort entries in Cognito Forms?

Tags: cognito-forms

Is there a way to filter or sort responses beyond 'pending', 'completed' and 'paid/unpaid'? I am a new user converting from Adobe FormsCentral. I would like to be able to sort my form entries by the data in the form fields, i.e. sort all entries in last name alpha order. I would also like to filer the entries by response, i.e., entries with the same date selection. I know I can export to Excel to do the sort and filter, but I would like to be able to do this on in Cognito entries database.

Answer (score 1):

I am a developer for [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com).

Although we do not yet offer this kind of search function. We are in the process us adding more functionality to our search option on the Entry page. You can follow our progress as we move forward with this feature over on our [Idea Board](https://trello.com/c/T0qvZ1uq). Feel free to up vote this feature and other features that you would like to see us work on for future releases.